# How to run java task for each file in directory?

Tags: java, ant, directory

How to run java task for each file in directory with Apache Ant? Looks like `<apply>` only allows to run executable.

Answer (score 0):

Either use apply with executable java.exe like this :

```
<apply executable="path/to/java.exe">
  <arg value="..."/>
  <arg value="..."/>
   ...
  <fileset dir="..."/>
   ...
</apply>
```

or use some AntAddon that provides a for loop, i.e. [Flaka](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/), see [Wiki examples / Files + Directories](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/wiki/FlakaExamples) :
Question : After compiling my java sources how to run the corresponding classes ?
Solution : Iterate over the fileset which contains the java sources and use the replace function to call the corresponding class files.

```
<project xmlns:fl="antlib:it.haefelinger.flaka">

  <property name="srcroot" value="path/to/srcrootdir"/>
  <property name="classroot" value="path/to/classrootdir"/>

  <!-- seek all classes with main method -->
  <fileset dir="${srcroot}" includes="**/*.java" id="mainclasses">
    <contains text="public static void main"/>
  </fileset>

  <!-- iterate over classes with main method and call
       corresponding classfile -->
  <fl:for var="file" in="split('${toString:mainclasses}', ';')">
    <fl:let>
      ; strip the '.java' extension
      file = replace(file, '', '.java')
      ; replace fileseparator with '.'
      ; when running on windows you have to use :
      ; replace(file, '\.', '${file.separator}${file.separator}')
      file = replace(file, '\.', '${file.separator}')
      </fl:let>
    <fl:echo>
      starting => #{file} in ${classroot}..
    </fl:echo>
    <java classname="#{file}">
      <classpath>
       <!--
         when using a fileset you'll get a
         java.util.zip.ZipException because you're
         referencing not jarfiles but classfiles
         therefore you've to use pathelement location
       -->
       <pathelement location="${classroot}"/>
      </classpath>
    </java>
  </fl:for>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<java>` task from [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html). But it can't apply itself to fileset.
[Example](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ant-user/200608.mbox/%3CB0057519178@securemail.onebox.com%3E)